# Exiobase hybrid 3 import missing JSON datapackage

Tags: brightway

With the following package versions:

bw2data 4.0.dev18

bw2io 0.9.dev10

The following code:

```
import bw2io as bi
ebhyb3 = bi.Exiobase3HybridImporter(dirpath_ebhyb3, db_name='EXIOBASE 3.3.17 hybrid')
```

outputs the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\dfont\CONSTRUCIA S.L\LCSA - General\Code\test.py in line 1
----> 210 ebhyb3 = bi.Exiobase3HybridImporter(dirpath_ebhyb3, db_name='EXIOBASE 3.3.17 hybrid')

File c:\Users\dfont\Anaconda3\envs\bw25\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\exiobase3_hybrid.py:26, in Exiobase3HybridImporter.__init__(self, dirpath, db_name)
     23 self.dirpath = Path(dirpath)
     24 self.db_name = db_name
---> 26 activities = mrio_common_metadata.get_metadata_resource(
     27     self.dirpath, "activities"
     28 )
     29 products = mrio_common_metadata.get_metadata_resource(self.dirpath, "products")
     31 product_to_activities = {i["id"]: j["id"] for i, j in zip(products, activities)}

File c:\Users\dfont\Anaconda3\envs\bw25\Lib\site-packages\mrio_common_metadata\__init__.py:40, in get_metadata_resource(dirpath, resource_name)
     39 def get_metadata_resource(dirpath, resource_name):
---> 40     resource = _get_resource(dirpath, resource_name)
     41     names = [f["name"] for f in resource["schema"]["fields"]]
     42     data = load_compressed_csv(Path(dirpath) / resource["path"])

File c:\Users\dfont\Anaconda3\envs\bw25\Lib\site-packages\mrio_common_metadata\__init__.py:22, in _get_resource(dirpath, resource_name)
     21 def _get_resource(dirpath, resource_name):
---> 22     resources = _get_resources(dirpath)
     23     assert len([r for r in resources if r["name"] == resource_name]) == 1
     24     return next(r for r in resources if r["name"] == resource_name)
...
     11     dirpath = Path(dirpath)
---> 12     assert (dirpath / "datapackage.json").is_file()
     13     return dirpath

AssertionError:
```

According to https://presamples.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/:

`datapackage.json: A JSON file following the datpackage standard with the metadata for these presamples. This is the only file that is required for a presample directory.`

What information exactly should this JSON contain and is it available somewhere?

Comment: Please provide a more complete error traceback - the current one is not enough to find out where you have having an error. Basically, the whole wall of text when you get an error. The command `assert (dirpath / "datapackage.json").is_file()` doesn't appear in the current brightway2data or brightway2io code. You should also give us the versions of `bw2data` and `bw2io` you are using.

Comment: I edited the original post to include the requested info.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to convert exiobase (hybrid units) version 3.3.17 into the format that is expected by the importer using [the code here](https://github.com/brightway-lca/bw_exiobase). Then you can run the importer.

```
from bw2io.importers.exiobase3_hybrid import Exiobase3HybridImporter

ei = Exiobase3HybridImporter(path_to_exiobase)
```

Comment: Thanks Nabla, but it seems that the bw_exiobase package cannot be found, see https://github.com/brightway-lca/bw_exiobase/issues/4